# How can solve this nonlinear system?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Someone help me to solve this system\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\ddot{x}_1(s) -\alpha \, x_1(s) \,\ddot{x}_2(s) &= 0 \\ \\
\ddot{x}_2(s) -\alpha \, x_1(s) \,\ddot{x}_1(s) - \alpha \, \dot{x}_1^2(s) &= 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Thank you in advance

Comment: from where Comes this System?

Comment: Based on a calculation made for  compute the Lagrangian of an unbounded operator on $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: To start with, it is useful to notice that $x_2$ only appears as a second derivative.

Comment: @ Paul, if we replace $x_2$ by its expression in the first equation, the system remains somewhat complicated

Comment: $$x_1(s)=\frac{1}{\alpha},x_2(s)=C_1s+C_2$$ is one solution